# Azure AD How to restrict an App from getting the users email address?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have set up an Azure active directory APP so that it uses the following endpoints to log a user in:

1. https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanId/oauth2/authorize
2. https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanId/oauth2/token

I have granted permission to the Microsoft Graph API but all I made available was the "Sign users in" in the Enable access section.
I am trying to work out if it is possible to not retrieve anything but an immutable id from the login process.
Looking at permissions it seems that the moment I grant permission to log in I am also granting permission to access my user details. Is it possible to set this up so that I only grant permission to login but not retrieve any user details using this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to set this up so that I only grant permission to login
>   but not retrieve any user details using this version?

It's not possible.

When you give permission to user sign in, it will also let app can read user profile. [**The permission**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) dispaly string is `Sign-in and read user profile` and its name is `User.Read`.

> Decription:   Allows users to sign-in to the app, and allows the app to
>   read the profile of signed-in users. It also allows the app to read
>   basic company information of signed-in users.

**Why:**

Based on Oauth/ODIC, when you use AAD Accounts to sign in your app (authentication/authorization your app via AAD), you can sign in with AAD accounts, it must need read user profile. Otherwise, your app cannot know who the user is and cannot do authentication/authorization. **This is a basic permission which your app needs if it let the user sign in.**